# Time reversal $t\rightarrow -t$: $0,10,20,30,40,50$ to $-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0$ or $0,-10,-20,-30,-40,-50\;?$

Tags: time-reversal-symmetry

**Time reversal symmetry** is defined as $$T:t\mapsto-t\;.$$

Suppose, a stroboscopic film of a ll falling from a certain height to the ground is run *forward* with time-instances given as: $0,10,20,30,40,50\;.$

When the film is run *backward*, the ball would move up having the same velocity at each place during its descend but now in the opposite *upward* direction.

But, what would be the *time-reversal* sequence?

Would it be $-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0$ or $0,-10,-20,-30,-40,-50\;?$

For me, it would be the former as the *reversal* definition says $t\rightarrow -t$ which implies, IMO, $50\rightarrow -50; \; 40\rightarrow -40$ etcetera.

That is $$\text{Forward}\\ \begin{array}{|c|c|}  t& v \\ \hline 0& v_1\\ 10& v_2\\ 20& v_3 \\ 30& v_4\\ 40& v_5\\ 50& v_6\end{array}$$

Which is correct:

$$\text{Backward}\\ \begin{array}{|c|c|}  t& v \\ \hline -50& -v_6\\ -40& -v_5\\ -30& -v_4 \\ -20& -v_3\\ -10& -v_2\\ 0& -v_1\end{array}$$ or $$\text{Backward}\\ \begin{array}{|c|c|}  t& v \\ \hline 0& -v_6\\ -10& -v_5\\ -20& -v_4 \\ -30& -v_3\\ -40& -v_2\\ -50& -v_1\end{array}$$?

If it is former, then the velocity function must be odd that is $v(-50)= -v(50)\;$ now since, *time-reversal* negates velocity, does that mean the velocity function must always have to be an odd function? This would be ridiculous to think there would only be *odd* velocity function; neither *even* nor *otherwise*. That's why I'm in doubt whether *time-reversal* sequence would be the first one.

So, can anyone please explain this to me which would be the *time-reversal* sequence?

Comment: One question per post! The part you edited in (which I rolled back) would make a good separate followup question though, so I'd encourage you to post it separately. (Extra benefit: more free reputation)

Comment: @David Z: Done. Check this: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232043/why-does-time-reversal-mean-negation-of-time-t-mapsto-t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your talk of the "sequence" of times does not make formal sense, but time reversal is indeed the map $t\mapsto -t$, so $50\mapsto -50$, etc.
2. The velocity is *not* constrained to be an odd or even function of time. That time reversal "negates" the velocity does *not* mean that $v(-t) = -v(t)$. It means that $v(t)\mapsto -v(t)$ under the time reversal map, but the point is that the image of $v(t)$ under $t\mapsto -t$ is *not* $v(-t)$. Look at the definition of velocity, which is $ v(t_0) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right\rvert_{t=t_0}$,
   so we have 
   $$v(t_0) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right\rvert_{t=t_0}\mapsto \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}(-t)}\right\rvert_{-t=-t_0} = \left.-\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\right\rvert_{-t=-t_0} = -v(t_0)$$
   given that you already know that $x$ doesn't change under time reversal. Again, that $x$ doesn't change doesn't mean that $x(t) = x(-t)$, it means $x(t_0)\mapsto x(t_0)$ under time reversal.
3. I can see how this is confusing. If you are familiar with a bit of geometry, the following explanation might help: We imagine here a "time manifold", which is just $\mathbb{R}$. On it, we have *scalars*, and *vectors*, but since the vectors are one-dimensional, we cannot really distinguish them from scalars if we have fixed a parametrization of time $t$. But: We are free to choose any parametrization of time that we like, in particular, we can choose to use $t' = -t$ instead of $t$. The scalars (such as $x$) don't care, but anything that's a vector - i.e. contains a single time derivative - will change its sign in the *natural basis for vectors* that comes with this parametrization. (Usually, you will have that the change of basis of the tangent vectors is the Jacobian. In one dimension, the Jacobian is simply the number $\frac{\mathrm{d}t'}{\mathrm{d}t} = -1$.)